# How to add Etag and Last Modified Header on IIS 10 and ASP Clasic?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How could I to add Last modified Headers and Last Modified header on IIS 10 with an ASP Clasic Page?

If I check for example the headers of test.html IIS 10 give me this response

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 12:57:15 GMT
ETag: "5895395521b8d61:0"
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 11:53:55 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Option: deny
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

But if we check the header of test.asp IIS give me this response header

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 149
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 12:53:54 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Option: deny
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I checked that there isn´t any header define on HTTP response Header Section on IIS and the Output Caching is enable with Enable Kernel Cache option.

Comment: You are saying "ASP Classic" but tagging this as ASP.NET. Which is it? The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @mason I don´t know why IIS by default send this header but I am running the pools on clasic mode and the code it´s asp clasic I think that´s only the value of the header X-Powered-by I will hide in the future because I don´t want to show information about the server or code.

Comment: How do you know it's ASP Classic? What are the extensions of the files you're trying to serve?

Comment: “HTTP/1.1 servers should send Last-Modified whenever feasible.” for dynamic content some sites may not keep track of the last modification date. you could try to disable the cache in iis. and if you still want to set then you could use iis custom header to manually set it.